# Partitioning with Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I'm having an issue with Hive creating a table from .avro files stored in multiple directories. Such as ParentDir with Child1, Child2, Child3, Child4 as subdirectiories. Each Child Subdirectory have multiple .avro files. I tried with the following syntax to create a table but it's working only on 1 subdir at a time. How can i make the partitions to involve all the subdirs at once?
Thanks!

Edited:
     Example of dirs:
        /ParentDir/brand-Child1/part-m-0000.avro
        /ParentDir/brand-Child2/part-m-0000.avro
        /ParentDir/brand-Child3/part-m-0000.avro
        /ParentDir/brand-Child4/part-m-0000.avro

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE  test    
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'    
STORED AS 
INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'    
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
LOCATION '/user/test/dir_with_avro_files/'    
TBLPROPERTIES 
('avro.schema.url'='/user/test/schema.avsc');
```

FIXED with this

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test
PARTITIONED BY(brand STRING)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.avro.AvroSerDe'
STORED AS
INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.avro.AvroContainerOutputFormat'
TBLPROPERTIES
('avro.schema.url'='/user/test/schema');
ALTER TABLE db.test ADD PARTITION (brand="child1") LOCATION '/user/test/output/brand-child1';
ALTER TABLE db.testADD PARTITION (brand="child2") LOCATION '/user/test/output/brand-child2';
ALTER TABLE db.testADD PARTITION (brand="child3") LOCATION '/user/test/output/brand-child3';
ALTER TABLE db.testADD PARTITION (brand="child4") LOCATION '/user/test/output/brand-child4';
```

Comment: Solved. With many alter tables instances after the creation statement.

Comment: Add that as a solution and accept it as the answer for posterity please.